# Applying a control signal to a control system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

A usual dynamical system can be described by an ordinary differential equation. Control systems have a variable $u$ which is to be chosen to get the desired dynamic behaviour.

Once this $u$ is plugged in, whether it is an open- or closed-loop system, do we end up with a common dynamical system just as in the theory of differential equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, with "usual/common dynamical system", you mean a set of ordinary differential equations (ODEs), then in general no. Because it depends on the control $u$. If you have an uncontrolled dynamical system ($u=0$) represented by an ODE

$$
\dot{x} = f(x, u)
$$

then it depends on your choice of $u$, if the controlled system is still an ODE.

For example, you could choose a $u$ that contains time delays. Then, the closed loop system would be a [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation) (FDE), not an ODE anymore. Or you could choose a $u$ that contains some randomness, then you would get a [stochastic differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation) (SDE), and so on.

So you have to choose $u$ "right" in order to get an ODE again.

Comment: Ah right, maybe a better question is "If we apply a control to a controlled dynamical system does it turn in to a common dynamical system?"


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system_(definition)

Comment: by the way open loop does not imply $u$ being zero I think

Comment: @oxire true, I changed that. However, then I don't really understand your question. There are (basically) only two options: Either you plug in some $u$ (feedback or feedforward), or you don't plug in anything, then its $u \equiv 0$. In both cases, you will still have a dynamical system. If this system is representable by a set of ODEs depends on both your uncontrolled system and the expression you plug in for $u$.

Comment: oh, by not plugging in $u$ I still have a $u$ in the expression. Thats what I mean

Comment: In practise you can't just leave $u$ in the expression. If you don't plug in anything for $u$, that means that you are not implementing any controller and that means that $u \equiv 0$.